# Aloha editor set Base url

Tags: aloha-editor

I want to move the aloha.js file out of the lib folder. Since this would break the path configuration I wanted to change the baseUrl in my Aloha.settings:

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    if (window.Aloha === undefined || window.Aloha === null) {
        window.Aloha = {};
    }
    window.Aloha.settings = {
        baseUrl: '/src/lib/',
        plugins: {
            load: ['common/ui', ' common/format', 'common/image', 'extra/ribbon', 'custom/color', 'custom/imageUpload']
        }
    };
})(window);
```

The baseUrl is set to /src/lib/ which is the location the aloha.js file is originally in, so all paths should be calculated from it.

However now I get the following error:

```
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'extendObjects'
```

and none of the files are loaded. Any ideas?

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Aloha escapes one directory up. So when you do

```
baseUrl: '/src/lib/',
```

for plugins it is:

```
'/src/lib/../',
```

Maybe that will help ;)

---

This error is shown becouse aloha is running, I think. There could be problem w jQuery instances, do you have other jquery loaded than 1.7.2?